# Numpy: flat a dictionary

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I am struggling with something apparently realy easy...
given a simple dictionary with integers as keys and lists as values

```
a = {}

a[0] = ['HI','HOME']
a[1] = ['tree','car', 'food']

print(a)    
{0: ['HI', 'HOME'], 1: ['tree', 'car', 'food']}
```

I want to get a list/np.array of only the keys:

```
[0,0,1,1,1]
```

I tried to look for a map function but I haven't found anything...
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Using `np.repeat` and `map(len..)` -

```
np.repeat(a.keys(), map(len,a.values()))
```

Sample run -

```
In [152]: a
Out[152]: {0: ['HI', 'HOME'], 1: ['tree', 'car', 'food']}

In [153]: np.repeat(a.keys(), map(len,a.values()))
Out[153]: array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1])
```

Or, we can use a list comprehension to get the lengths. Thus, `map(len,a.values()` could be replaced by -

```
[len(i) for i in a.values()]
```

For `Python 3.x`, I believe, we need to wrap `list` with `map` -

```
In [39]: np.repeat(list(a.keys()), [len(i) for i in a.values()])
Out[39]: array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1])
```

Comment: In python 3 `np.repeat` doesn't accept `keys` object. You have to convert it to list. Also using one list comprehension I think would be more optimized in most cases than doing all this operations and function calls.

Comment: @Kasramvd Thanks! Updated on it.

Answer (score 2):

I think the most optimized way (specially for short and medium sized arrays) is using a nested list comprehension like following:

```
In [66]: [key for key, val in a.items() for _ in val]
Out[66]: [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

Here is a benchmark with other answer (by far faster):

```
In [75]: %timeit np.repeat(list(a.keys()), list(map(len, a.values())))
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.18 us per loop

In [76]: %timeit [key for key, val in a.items() for _ in val]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 558 ns per loop
```

For largest data sets you should use numpy but with some changes in calculating the keys and length of values:

```
a = {i:[3, 4, 5]*1000 for i in range(1000)}

In [86]: %timeit [key for key, val in a.items() for _ in val]
10 loops, best of 3: 54.7 ms per loop

In [87]: %timeit np.repeat(list(a.keys()), list(map(len, a.values())))
100 loops, best of 3: 9.18 ms per loop

In [88]: %timeit np.repeat(list(a), [len(i) for i in a.values()])
100 loops, best of 3: 9.12 ms per loop
```

Comment: Add timings for bigger dataset?

Comment: Could you also add the setup to create the larger `a`?

Comment: @Divakar I was about that add that too. Just updated.

Comment: @Divakar I didn't involve the dictionary creation in timeit!

Comment: I didn't mean to include the setup of creating `a` into timeit. I meant that so that I could see how big is the largest dataset and use that setup at my end and and also test out the timings at my end.

Comment: 0@Divakar Think nothing of it ;)

Comment: `[[key]*len(val) for ...]` should produce `[[0,0],[1,1,1]]`.  It can be flattened with the itertools.chain` idiom.

Comment: @hpaulj That's a nice short way! but not as fast as the nested list comprehension ;).